# Add Row Count in Caption of Gridview ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to add row count information in gridview caption?
I write this code in design source. But it not work.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="WindowFrame" Caption="Number of records: <%# gvData.Rows.Count %>">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it not work" exactly? You get exception, error message or unexpected result? Can you please be more specific? Also did you debug your code and see what `gvData.Rows.Count` returns?

Comment: @SonerGönül it show **Number of records: <%# gvData.Rows.Count %>** in caption. not the right value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use OnDataBound event:

```
protected void gvData_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gvData.Caption = $"Number of records:{gvData.Rows.Count.ToString()}";
        }
```